# mail issues "535 Authentication credentials invalid"

Tags: arch-linux, ssmtp, 1and1

I'm trying to send mails from command line with my 1and1 credentials.

But if the following configuration worked to send mails from my nexcloud server :

- send mode : `smtp`
- encryption : `SSL/TLS`
- from address : `contact`@`mydomain.fr`
- Authentication method : `login`
- Authentication required : `yes`
- server address : `auth.smtp.1and1.fr`:`465`
- Credentials : `contact@mydomain.fr` - `mypassword`

The following configuration and command still fail :

**/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf :**

```
AuthUser=contact@mydomain.fr
AuthPass=mypassword
mailhub=auth.smtp.1and1.fr:465
rewriteDomain=mydomain.fr
UseTLS=YES
```

**/etc/ssmtp/revaliases :**

```
vmonteco:contact@mydomain.fr:auth.smtp.1and1.fr:465
```

**command line :**

```
$ echo test | mail -v -s "Test" mymail@hotmail.fr
mail: Loading /etc/mail.rc
mail: No such file to load: /home/vmonteco/.mailrc
mail: Setting up PseudoRandomNumberGenerator: *SSL RAND_*
[<-] 220 kundenserver.de (mreue105) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready
[->] EHLO localhost.localdomain
[<-] 250 SIZE 69920427
[->] AUTH LOGIN
[<-] 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[->] Y29udGFjdEB2b250ZWNvLm5pbmph
[<-] 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[<-] 535 Authentication credentials invalid
sendmail: Authorization failed (535 Authentication credentials invalid)
```

Is there something I forgot?

**EDIT :**

I also tried with port 25 and without TLS

Answer (score -1):

I finally restarted from scratch and I had to use [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37061/136611), use port `465` instead of `587`, and [use `rewriteDomain`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42095206/3156085).

So finally my configuration file finally looked like :

```
root=contact@mydomain.fr
mailhub=auth.smtp.1and1.fr:465
AuthUser=contact@mydomain.fr
AuthPass=mypassword
rewriteDomain=mydomain.fr
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

Which is even simpler since I don't use `revaliases` file.

Comment: The things you said you changed are the same as the original configuration you asserted.